# Is that a bad Javascript practice I'm doing here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management

for some reason I do that every time because I find it clean. I declare variables on top to use them below. I do that even if I use them only once.

Here is an example (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework) :

```
$("#tbListing").delegate("a.btnEdit", "click", function(e) {
    var storeId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id").replace("store-", ""),
        storeName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").html(),
        $currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    $currentRow.addClass("highlight");

    $("#dialogStore")
        .data("mode", "edit")
        .data("storeId", storeId)
        .data("storeName", storeName)
        .dialog( "open" );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I tend to do that in `PHP` too. Am I right if I believe it's not very memory efficient to do that ?

**Edit:** Thank you for all the answers. You have all given good answers. About that code optimisation now. Is that better now ?

```
            $("#tbListing").delegate("a.btnEdit", "click", function(e) {
                var $currentRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
                    storeId = this.rel, /*storing the storeId in the edit button's rel attribute now*/
                    storeName = $currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();

                $currentRow.addClass("highlight");

                $("#dialogStore")
                    .data("info", {
                        "mode" : "edit",
                        "storeId" : storeId,
                        "storeName" : storeName
                    }) /*can anyone confirm that overusing the data isn't very efficient*/
                    .dialog( "open" );


                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Comment: repeating $(this).closest("tr") could be avoided ;)

Comment: I don't want comments like : Hey you're doing it wrong because you store informations in the "id" attributes or something or you should store information only once in the data using an object. I only want to know how bad is it to the memory/browser's allowed memory doing that.

Comment: @Caspar, yep I'm aware of that. I could simply store the `$(this).closest("tr")` in a variable so jQuery don't have to run the DOM every time. :P

Comment: Err... I could declare `$currentRow` on top and use it below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, are you asking if it's OK to declare variables even if you're using them once?

Absolutely! It makes the code a million times more readable if you name things properly with a variable. Readability should be your primary concern. Memory efficiency should only be a concern if it proves problematic.

As Knuth said,

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

If you're asking more about declaring the variables at the beginning of the function, rather than where they are first used, then [Emmett has it right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692301/is-that-a-bad-javascript-practice-im-doing-here/4692333#4692333) - Crockford recommends doing this in JavaScript to avoid scope-related confusion. Whether it's worth it in PHP is a purely subjective question I'd say, but there's nothing wrong with keeping your PHP and JS coding styles similar.

---

One more CS quote (from Abelson and Sussman's [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)):

> programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.

Comment: 97% in the 70's. Now it's more 99.97%

Comment: so your saying you should only worry about memory efficiency when it happens (because memory efficiency is always problematic by its nature), thats poor future proofing. Surely readability is second to function?

Comment: @benhowdle I'm saying you should worry about memory efficiency only in the rare cases that it affects function.

Comment: I think though, that the OP is asking about general good practices. There's a difference between hunting for optimizations that don't exist and just generally trying to write efficient, tight code as a rule. I don't think the quote above is a license to write sloppy code and only worry about it when it causes problems. You'll end up with a lot more problems that way.

Comment: @benhowdle: readability is first, and foremost. you cannot optimize what you can't read

Comment: @MattC There's a difference between writing sloppy code and writing code that favours readability over memory efficiency. I'd say it's much more important to name things sensibly than to worry about the memory an extra variable will take.

Comment: @benhowdle Sure it is, but you still need to prioritise something. And I'm saying prioritise readability.

Comment: Fair enough, i'm not knocking you personally, i just disagree

Answer (score 6):

It's not bad practice.

> The var statements should be the first statements in the function body.
>
> ---
>
> JavaScript does not have block scope,
> so defining variables in blocks can
> confuse programmers who are
> experienced with other C family
> languages. Define all variables at the
> top of the function.

http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: Not everyone agrees with everything Crockford says, not least on this particular point. I certainly don't.

Comment: @Tim so where do you suggest that variables be defined?

Comment: Eh? In the example code given, the `var` statement *is* the first line in the function body.

Comment: @Spudley He's saying "No it's not bad practice" I think.

Comment: @Skilldrick: ah, an ambiguously written answer then. thanks for clarifying :) (@Emmett: sorry if I misunderstood you)

Comment: @Spludley I replaced "No" with "It's not bad practice" for clarity.

Comment: People that sprinkle variable definitions all over the place are evil and should be punished.

Comment: @Emmett: I prefer to declare variables close to where they're used, although I have no objection to people declaring them all at the top of the function (I have had a phase of doing this myself). I don't think it requires a Crockford "this is best practice"-style mandate either way.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables at the top is a good thing to do.  It makes the code more readable.  In your particular example, you could replace $(this).closest('tr') witha  variable, as suggested int eh comments, but in general I find code with descriptive variable names all in one place very readable.

Answer (score 1):

nah, I'd say you're doing exactly the right thing.

As @Caspar says, you could simplify your code by setting `$currentRow` first and using that instead of `$(this).closest("tr")` in the other two lines.  And there may be a few other things you could improve. But setting vars at the begining of a function the way you've done it is absolutely a good thing.

Particuarly good because you've done it inside the function, so they're local variables, which means they get thrown away at the end of the function, so no memory usage issues there.

If you'd set them as global vars, it might have been more of an issue, although to be honest even then, since you're just setting pointers to an existing object, it wouldn't be using a huge amount of memory even then (though it would be polluting the global namespace, which isn't good)

Comment: +1 Thank you, you have specified that they are thrown away after the execution because they are local variable. I thought that but I wasn't sure.

Comment: I would like to know the **a few other things you could improve**. I edited my questions and included an (I believe) optimised version of it. Mind taking a look at it ?